# Terminology: canonical member of equivalence class

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology, equivalence-relations, set-partition

An equivalence relation $R$ partitions a set $X$ into equivalence classes. It is common to denote the equivalence class of an element $x \in X$ as $[x] = \{u \in X \mid u R x\}$. However, this leads to a given equivalence class having multiple names: one for each element of the class. Is there a convention identifying a canonical element/name of a class, or a name for this canonical label?

---

As an example, let’s use the congruence relation modulo 3 on the natural numbers $\mathbb N^+$. There are three equivalence classes. One of them can reasonably be called $[1]$, $[4]$, $[136]$, $[850000123]$, or by infinitely many other names.

To make it clear that we are always referring to the same thing, we may choose to always call this class $[1]$, selecting 1 as a privileged representative of the class. (I chose it because it is the minimum element, but the criterion seems unimportant, so long as there is a criterion.)

---

Is there a name, either for a privileged representative $k$ of a given class, or for a canonical label $[k]$?

Comment: I've heard "canonical representative".

Comment: “Canonical representative” is the way to go. Often, people will choose a “system of representatives” $S$ such that $S$  contains precisely one element of each equivalence class (this requires, or rather essentially *is* the axiom of choice in general, but in concrete situations constructive versions might be available). You’d then always choose $s \in S$ to represent a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You touch a nontrivial question since the existence of such a selector function is the [axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice). [Hilbert's epsilon calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_calculus) and Bourbaki's tau-square notation are two formal approaches for this question.

That being said, there is often in practice a natural choice. For instance, for the case of the congruence modulo $k$ on $\Bbb N$, you can choose the rest of the Euclidean division of $n$ by $k$ to represent the equivalence class.

Comment: Ooh, didn’t mean to go into the deep end of set theory! I see this claim on the Wikipedia article for the axiom of choice: “Suppose that each member of the collection X is a nonempty subset of the natural numbers. Every such subset has a smallest element, so to specify our choice function we can simply say that it maps each set to the least element of that set. This gives us a definite choice of an element from each set, and makes it unnecessary to apply the axiom of choice.” That aligns nicely with your second paragraph.